# SSRS parameters dynamically passed to other reports

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2.

This one is hard to describe.  I have a report that has a main report on top and 10 sub reports below it.  The main report ranks the top 10 industries by revenue. The sub reports are detailed reports within the ranked industries. But they need to be dynamic.  So for August, if the #1 industry is AUTO, the sub-report for AUTO appears in position 1.  Then in September, if the #1 industry is RETAIL, the sub-report for RETAIL needs to appear in position 1.  For example ...

```
August --> 
MAIN REPORT:   1. AUTO
        2. RETAIL
        3. FOOD

SUB REPORTS: POS 1=AUTO, POS 2=RETAIL, POS 3=FOOD

September --> 
MAIN REPORT:   1. RETAIL
        2. FOOD
        3. CONSUMER

SUB REPORTS: POS 1=RETAIL, POS 2=FOOD, POS 3=CONSUMER
```

Note that the sub reports order changes depending on the main report. The sub report accepts the Industry name parameter but I don't know how to dynamically change the parameter.

I tried the CHOOSE function as the value of the Industry parameter and it works if I pass it an explicit string of values.  I'd love to be able to pass it an array. I tried passing a dataset name but it just thinks its another string value.

```
  =CHOOSE(1,"AUTO","TRAVEL","FINANCIAL",...)
```

`LOOKUP` fails because I can't use a Field in the parameter statement.

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks, all!

-- Since I can't upload a picture, I'm going to attempt to build a diagram to show you how this would look. Imagine the SSRS work area. There is a main report and several sub reports. I'm using the dots to simulate spaces. Notice that the order of the sub reports change to match the order of the rank in the main report. So what I need to do is pass the industry parameter from the main to the sub reports dynamically.

Main Report - **August**

**Rank...Industry...Revenue** 

 1........AUTO.........$333
 
 2........RETAIL......$222
 3........FOOD........$111

Sub Reports - **August**
**.........AUTO**

**Rank...COMPANY...Revenue** 

 1........TOYOTA........$555
 
 2........HONDA.........$111
 3........LEXUS..........$99

**.........RETAIL**

**Rank...COMPANY...Revenue** 

 1........WALMART........$45
 
 2........TARGET.........$35
 3........COSTCO..........$25

**.........FOOD**

**Rank...COMPANY...Revenue** 

 1........KROGER........$888
 
 2........MOMS............$277
 3........FOOD CITY....$150

Main Report - **September**

**Rank...Industry...Revenue** 

 1........RETAIL.........$333
 
 2........FOOD..........$222
 3........CONSUMER........$111

Sub Reports - **September**
**.........RETAIL**

**Rank...COMPANY...Revenue** 

 1........TARGET........$555
 
 2........JC PENNY.........$111
 3........DILLARDS..........$99

**.........FOOD**

**Rank...COMPANY...Revenue** 

 1........FOOD CITY........$45
 
 2........KROGER.........$35
 3........RALPHS..........$25

**.........CONSUMER**

**Rank...COMPANY...Revenue** 

 1........P&G...........$888
 
 2........KIMBERLY............$277
 3........J&J..........$150

Comment: please upload sample images

Comment: I attempted too but got an error that I have to be a level 10 to upload images.  I pretty new to Stack Overflow so don't have the privileges yet.

Comment: Well I am not sure what you want but i have feeling that i can help you but without correct understanding its difficutlt

Comment: I've added a mock up of the reports. Hopefully that will make things clearer.

Comment: Let me know still if you have any question'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 report
1) Main Report
2) Sub Report

Note : Sample Image attached
-- Output 
[image: Output]
Parameter for Sub Report

[image: ParameterSelect for SubReport]
Main Report Layout

[image: MainReport Layout]
Subreport Layout

[image: SubReport Layout]
2 Parameter created for Sub Report

[image: Create 2 Parameter in SubReport]

Datasource

```
---------- Data Source for Main Report
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Main'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Main
    (
        [Rank] INT,
        Indusry VARCHAR(500),
        Revenue INT,
        [MONTH] int
    )

    INSERT INTO #Main VALUES(1,'AUTO',333,8)
    INSERT INTO #Main VALUES(2,'RETAIL',222,8)
END
SELECT * FROM #Main
------------------ Data source for Sub Report
DECLARE @Industry VARCHAR(50)
SET @Industry ='Auto'

DECLARE @Month Int  
SET @Month =8


IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AUTO')) 
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #AUTO
(
    [Rank] INT,
    Indusry VARCHAR(500),
    Revenue INT,
    [MONTH] int
)
INSERT INTO #AUTO VALUES(1,'TOYOTA',34,8)
INSERT INTO #AUTO VALUES(2,'HONDA',44,8)
END


IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RETAIL')) 
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #RETAIL
(
    [Rank] INT,
    Indusry VARCHAR(500),
    Revenue INT,
    [MONTH] int
)

INSERT INTO #RETAIL VALUES(1,'WALMART',55,8)
INSERT INTO #RETAIL VALUES(2,'TARGET',44,8)
END 



IF @Industry ='Auto'
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM #AUTO WHERE [MONTH] = @Month
END
ELSE IF    @Industry ='Auto'
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM #RETAIL WHERE [MONTH] = @Month
END
```

Note : Base on Condition data will display into sub report.. parameter passed from parent report

Answer (score 0):

I think since you want it be dynamic and you have all the parts in place - the easiest way to do this would be to: Right click in the 'Industry' field in the main table, go to properties, select "Action", click the radio button "Go to Report" - click the expression button and add an IIF or Switch statement..

```
=IIF(Fields!Industry.Value = "Retail", Retailsubreportname, IIF(Fields!Industry.Value = "Auto", Autosubreportname, IIF(Fields!Industry.Value = "Food", Foodsubreportname, (this is the else- so anohter sr or a default reportname???)
or
=Switch(Fields!Industry.Value = "Retail","Retailsubreportname",Fields!Industry.Value = "Auto", "Autosubreportname")  etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved. Both RandomShelly and Sanjay gave me ideas to solve it.  Basically, I used Sanjay's idea of creating datasets that only contain the data for each ranked industry.  He used temp tables but I created permanent dataset definitions in the report.  So knowing that the first ranked industry will always be in position 1, I created a dataset called REPORT_POSITION_1 with the following definition:

```html
SELECT  *
FROM    TOP10_COMPANIES
WHERE NET = :Network
AND INDUSTRY = (SELECT DISTINCT INDUSTRY FROM TOP10_INDUSTRIES WHERE CURR_RANK=1 AND NET=:Network)
ORDER BY CURR_RANK
```

Note: my source database is Oracle so the ":" syntax for a parameter is correct. I've added the Network parameter since posting. Since the underlying tables only contain a snapshot of the data, I don't need the month parameter.

This dataset is ONLY made up of the data for the first industry so I don't need to use the Industry parameter at all.

Once the various datasets and reports are created, I used RandomShelly's idea of creating dynamic links to call the specific Industry reports through hyperlinks.  This will be perfect when I deploy to SharePoint in our dashboard for users to navigate to the information they are looking for.

Thanks to both of you for your help!

Comment: Great, please also provide votes if answer is useful